# Add Text to Mail Body with Python

Tags: python, email, postfix-mta

I'm trying to modify a mail body on the fly.
In my scenario I'm using python as a filter for postfix. 
I get the mail and can read every part.
My goal is to remove the attachment (`set_payload("")`) and add a info to the body of the mail. For `text/plain` and `text/html`.

But if I use attach() to add a MIMEText I only can this for the root payload element...

```
import email
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

foo = MIMEText("www.foooo.de")
foo
<email.mime.text.MIMEText instance at 0x7f4d12491320>
msg.get_payload()[0].get_payload()[0].attach(foo)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in 
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/message.py", line 166, in attach
>   self._payload.append(payload)
>   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

How can I add a line at the end of the plain and the html message?

Answer (score 1):

There is no append method in str. You can append text to string in that way:

```
string = 'foo'
string += 'bar'
```